# Sync Dailymotion videos

Tags: data-synchronization, data

I have Dailymotion app in my iPhone 4s iOS 8.3! Plz tell me how to sync Dailymotion videos so that I can watch them offline?

Answer (score 1):

Dailymotion does not have a provision to download the videos for off line viewing.

There is no setting in the Sync to do that.

You will need a another 3d party app to download the videos so you can watch them off line.

There is a number off applications to download videos, example https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-downloader-download/id733735644?mt=8

or this one http://mediatapdownloader.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-download-videos-from-dailymotion.html

and so on....Search for "Dailymotion" "Video download" in Apple Store.

Answer (score -1):

Try this App on AppStore that lets you cache dailymotion videos : CarbonPlay https://itunes.apple.com/app/carbonplay-multi-media-gadget/id1041534134?mt=8